# Current in a Brushless DC Motor

Tags: brushless-dc-motor

I'm attempting to design a BLDC Motor for theoretical use in an electric car and I'm having difficulty calculating the maximum current at various speeds.

Is there any equation I can use for this? I've already got the Torque/Voltage constant, so I know what voltages I need for what speeds. I also know there's a relationship between the voltage and current but I can't figure out how that would come into whatever equation.

Comment: If you want more help than posted below, you need to provide more information and specific questions.

Comment: Brian Drummond's answer helped me understand the concept where the current is dependant on the torque required, which hadn't before clicked in my head.

And Marko Bursic's answer gave the mathematical equation to go with that information.

As such, I am currently unable to accept either one of those as the sole answer

Answer (score 2):

$$T_m-J\frac{d²\Theta}{dt²}+F\frac{d\Theta}{dt}-T_L=0$$ 
$$T_m=k_Ti$$
Where \$T_m\$ is motor torque, \$T_L\$ is the load torque, \$J\$ is the moment of inertia, \$F\$ is the friction coefficient, \$\Theta\$ is the rotor angle. \$k_t\$ is torque constant.

There is no max. current vs. speed. It's just a nominal current which may not be exceeded if you look at the current as mean value. The peaks can be very high with respect to the nominal current, but they may not persist for long time - \$I^2t\$ limit.
If we ommit the transients of acceleraton/decelration and friction, then the formula becomes: \$T_m=T_L\$ or \$i=\dfrac{T_L}{k_T}\$

Comment: Can you add a description for what each of those symbols mean?

Answer (score 2):

Calculate the torque required to maintain various speeds. Include rolling resistance, wind resistance, the force required to accelerate the weight of the whole wehicle, and the force required to lift that weight up a 30% gradient at an acceptable speed (alternatively, use a lower gradient, but stay off Hardknott and Wrynose passes in the Lake District!)

Add a margin for friction in gearing etc.

From that, use the torque constant to calculate the current you need to generate that torque.